# How to install python and ase in linux without sudoer identity?

Tags: python, linux-headers

How can I install the [atomic simulation environment](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/) in my working directory? I am a normal user so I cannot use the "sudo" command. 
[image]

Here is the guide of ASE:

[image]

Can someone help me go through these procedures?

Comment: You can install `ase` without sudo `pip install ase`, but you cannot install python-pip without sudo.

Comment: Ask an administrator to install the necessary program packages for you :-)

Comment: Do you have access to `pip install --user ase`?  If you do, then use that; if you do not and `pip` shows as a nonexistent command, you'll have to talk to your sysadmin to get the proper packages made available.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have python and pip already installed, use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to install packages locally.  This works well for machines that have apps that require more than one version of python and/or packages (like an automated testing server).

If you don't have python, or if you need a specific version, download python from [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and build it for your use only.  Just use `./configure --prefix=/home/yourusername/python` to tell it to install in your home directory as your user instead of in /usr/local.  Use whatever install directory you wish that you have permission to.